# How can we disable a specific link from list of hyperlinks in Details tab in Pentaho report design?

Tags: hyperlink, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

There are 50 names in details tab with hyperlinks and I want to disable hyperlinks for few names in list of 50. Lets say 5 of them are unable to perform click events.

I have checked with on-click events and javascript and css also. But its hard for me to make changes on pentaho report design. I am expecting that I want some of data with hyperlinks and some without hyperlinks. I want to know how to make hyperlinks disable for some data values.